# I need some validation on a exponential decay function I came up with

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

I'm trying to solve a problem in my company I'd like to have some validation if my solution is going on right way.

I have a list of textual documents and I want to calculate a score based on the metadata of these documents. I have three features: two of these features are basically a float value between 0-5 and the third one is the date of the document. Since the score of the document should be smaller the older the document is, I thought an exponential decay would certainly apply here. So far, I came up with the following score:
$$
\mathrm{Score}(X,Y,t) = (\alpha X+\beta Y)e^{-\gamma t}
$$
$\alpha, \beta, \gamma $ are coefficients for the features of my documents. And $t$ would the date difference between now and the date of the document.

I don't know the values of the coefficients just yet, but my customer has a set of examples of the scores for a small collection of documents. I thought I could learn the coefficients for this score function based on this small annotated set. Since I just have three variables, I want to loop around possible values for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ (0-1 range) to get the smallest error for this score. The decay should be very slight, so I'm thinking on small values for $\gamma$, and also I may need to normalize $X$ and $Y$ because I'd like my result in the 0-1 range.

I'm very interested to know if I'm on the right track to solve this problem, and recommendations on how to improve my function.

Thank you so much,

Thiago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're on the right path. A few things to note however:

- If you want your output to be in the range of $[0,1]$, normalising $X$ and $Y$ won't do that for you, since you could have both of them at 1 and end up with a value greater than 1, with a $t$ value resulting in the score being larger than 1. If you want to make sure the function will always be in the range $[0,1]$, you'll need to divide by $5(\alpha+\beta)$ assuming that $X$ and $Y$ both fall within the range $[0,5]$. This just scales the function by the maximum so it'll never go above 1. This should be the value of the function when $X$ and $Y$ are 5, and $t$ is 0
- Linear functions are nice, but have a think about adding in some different functions for your $X$ and $Y4 variables, maybe even a constant, just make sure to update your divisor to normalise the function.

If you want a way to visualise your function as you're working on it, have a look at [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) to plot your functions. If you want to, you can use it as a [regression calculator](https://help.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/4406972958733-Regressions) as well to minimise error between your function and the set of scores you have.

Mainly, just play around with some functions (polynomials, logarithms, exponentials, etc.) and see what works best really. But so far, it seems pretty good.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insights. I'm definitely on the right track then. I'm normalizing the values, probably just dividing by 5 since $\alpha+\beta$ will be equal to one. I'm probably using a regression to calculate the coefficients, but I'm looking now into expanding the data first.